# Passing variable from one function to another function

Tags: php, class, function, variables, global-variables

I am trying to pass a variable from one function to another. I have several other functions that require $member_id which is provided in the first function wordpress_user_id().

```
function wordpress_user_id() {
    $member_id = get_current_user_id();         
    return $member_id;
}
```

I need to use $member_id in this function:

```
function yif_wlmm_get_wp_user_id() {
    $output = 'Your ID is: ' . $member_id;          
    return $output;
}
```

I tried passing $member_id from the first function like this:

```
function yif_wlmm_get_wp_user_id($member_ID)
```

and

```
function yif_wlmm_get_wp_user_id( wordpress_user_id() )
```

but neither one works.

```
yif_wlmm_get_wp_user_id( wordpress_user_id() )
```

does not return `$member_id`. Do I need to use a global?

Comment: That has nothing to with using classes or not.Look into the PHP manual on [function arguments](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php).

Answer (score 2):

To make that code pass anything, you need to do this:

```
$id = wordpress_user_id();
yif_wlmm_get_wp_user_id($id);
```

or, more concise:

```
yif_wlmm_get_wp_user_id(wordpress_user_id());
```

Otherwise the functions have nothing to do with each other, even if you name their parameters identically.

Whether a class is the better use or not is impossible to answer without knowing more about how this is used.